# Duplicate check while creating Google Contact with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-contacts, google-apps-script

I have the following code which creates Google Contacts from a Spreadsheet. The problem is whenever I run the code it creates contacts but has no functionality to check if the same Google Contact already exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code retrieves the contacts of the group first and checks whether an e-mail address corresponds to one of the sheet entries:

### Code

```
function bulk_cdb_one_way_sync(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cdb = ss.getSheetByName("Bulk_CDB").getDataRange().getValues();
  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("Preview List");
  var groupContacts = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("Preview List").getContacts();

  for (var x=1, xLen=cdb.length; x<xLen; x++) {
    var aContact = [];
    aContact.push(cdb[x][0], cdb[x][1], cdb[x][2], cdb[x][6]);
    var c = 0;  
    if(groupContacts.length > 0) {
      c =+ 1, u = 0;
      for(var i in groupContacts) {
        var emails = groupContacts[i].getEmails();
        for(var j in emails) {
          if(emails[j].getAddress() == aContact[2]) {
            u += 1;
            continue;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if(c === 0 || u == "undefined" || u === 0) {          
      var c = ContactsApp.createContact("There","Painter", aContact[2]);
        c.addCustomField("Metro 1", aContact[1]);
        c.addCustomField("Status", aContact[0]);
        c.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE, aContact[3]);
        c.addToGroup(group);
    }  
  }
}
```

### Explained

The `groupContacts` retrieves all available contacts in the group. The `x=1` makes sure to skip the header and the array (`aContact`) is created for easy access. If the group has no entries, then `c` will remain `0` and the new contacts will be added. Then the script will itterate over the contacts and over the e-mails present. If a match is found, `u` will be `> 0` and no contact is added.

### Remark

Make sure the data you about to add contains no duplicates.....

Comment: I tried with your code, still duplicate entries can be added to group. I there is no contact added to group then its not adding contact  ? any suggestions

Comment: @Noor this was one of my first `I did not test in advance` scripts. I hope this one works.